# Illustrator (.ai) file takes too much time to open

Tags: adobe-illustrator, brush, illustrator-effects

I created an illustration on 1200x900px artboard (72 ppi) and used some stipple brushes given here: https://blog.spoongraphics.co.uk/freebies/8-free-stipple-shading-brushes-for-adobe-illustrator

Now, while creating this illustration, the performance was okay, there weren't much lag or irritation. But it takes a little time to save it.

**Real problem:**

When I saved it, the file size was around **87 MB**. I closed Illustrator. When I opened it again, it took **1 hour** to open it!

I'm sure it has something to do with the stipple brushes. But I want to know what the possible resource it is missing which makes it too slow? I checked task manager at same time and I saw my NVIDIA GPU (**GeForce 940MX 4GB**)  was not used yet (*it runs only when Illustrator is fully open*), Intel GPU was used only **2%**. Even RAM was used **6.5** of 8 GB.

**My laptop specs are:** 8GB RAM, i7 8th Gen processor, GeForce 940MX 4GB GPU, Windows 10

Everything else works fine but I feel little frustrated when using these brushes and I think I should have bought MacBook Pro.

So the question is: Why my laptop is too slow in this case? Would the same file open quickly in MacBook Pro?

(Below are the screenshots of resources used and the illustration I made)

[image]

Comment: Sorry but GD.SE is not a tech support website. Performance issues are off-topic here.

Comment: Where can I ask this question?

Comment: Best to contact Adobe Support or try the Adobe Illustrator Forum.

Comment: Okay but I was really interested in knowing if resources aren't used (almost 0% GPU and RAM is still remaining free) fully, why is it slow? Where can I ask this?

Comment: Like AndrewH already said try the Adobe Illustrator Community https://forums.adobe.com/community/illustrator or try contacting Adobe directly. This is not an issue we can offer much help on, besides what Scott answered. I don't think there's a stack where this would be on-topic.

Comment: Can I improve this question to remove 1 downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Illustrator is and *always* has been a horribly slow, mud swilling, dog when you reach a point where there are too many objects... throw in ANY raster effects and that slow-down increases exponentially.

Ultimately **no** computer specifications matter. Ai can be slow on the most powerful system you can purchase. There is merely something in the core code base that, once reached, is a black hole for speed. A key tip here is a nearly 100MB vector file.... that's a bit larger than normal and would make me start to consider anti-slow down techniques (below).

In order to help when a file starts getting too slow, you may be able to do a few things to help speed it up a bit:

- Utilize **Symbols** whenever possible.
- Utilize **layers** and their visibility. Turning off visibility for layers can immediately improve speeds.
- Use **low resolution raster effects** until you are ready for output. By setting the Document Raster Effects Settings (DRES) in the Effects menu  to 72ppi you can greatly increase screen redraw speed. Then simply bump it up to 300PPI .. and wait... and wait.. and wait.. then save for final output.
- **Expand** raster effects whenever possible. Objects (Expanded effects) will always be faster than live, editable, effects.
- Keep type "live" as much as possible. Live type isn't seen the same as outlined type. Live type is 1 object, outlined type is an object for every shape.

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggestions. I didn't get the last point. Are you talking about View > Outline mode or something else?

Comment: The last bullet is merely stating to *not* outline type if possible.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there any stackexchange site where I could ask more about my tech query for which the question is on hold?

Comment: @VikasKumar typically questions regarding the overall function of any computer system or it's applications may better fit at http://www.SuperUser.com (A stack site)